# Get the original train-test split based on an integer column value after using pd.get_dummies

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, dummy-variable, train-test-split

I combined my train and test dataset and used get_dummies function from pandas to one hot encode categorical data. The reason behind concatenating was the number of levels in categorical data for train and test set were different.

If I use the get_dummies function on separate train and test set then I would get a dataframe of different dimension as out so I thought of combining them.

I want to now again split it into train and test set. Is it possible?

Assume that the output we get after using pd.get_dummies is named as 'dataset'. If the value of 'C10' column in dataset is 30(integer) then the data beleongs to test set otherwise it belongs to trainset.

If I try to select values like we do in a normal dataframe I get the following error:

```
dataset = pd.concat([train, test])
dataset_dummy = pd.get_dummies(dataset, prefix_sep='_', columns = cat_columns, sparse = True, drop_first = True)

test_dummy = dataset_dummy.iloc[dataset_dummy['day'] == 30]


AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T'
```

Comment: you haven't included enough code to reproduce the error message, maybe it has something to do with duplicate column names? https://github.com/cm3/lafayettedb_thumbnail_getter/issues/3

Comment: It is an attribute error. My guess is that the 'loc' function is not available for sparse Dataframe.

Comment: Nah, I am wrong about loc functionality. It is a very huge dataframe. Are you looking for any particular info. I will try to edit in the question.

Comment: can you reproduce the error with a small sample dataset that you can include as code in your question? I've never seen that error before and don't know how to help you?